# two dropdownlist

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdownlist boxes. If I click on the first dropdown box, then the values have been changed in the second listbox accordingly to first listbox.
For example:
One is Fruits,vegetables,Birds. If i click on the Fruits then it shows the fruit list items in the second list box. It is same for other list also.

Answer (score 3):

Hai Praveen,

Have a look at these examples for question reguarding cascading dropdown

http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/2053.html

http://www.skillfusion.com/articles/ajaxDropdown.php

http://codestips.com/php-ajax-cascading-dropdown-using-mysql/

http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread132703.html

http://www.weberdev.com/get_example-4505.html